# netscreen sn25 vs cisco asa5505 speed

Tags: firewall, cisco, juniper

Current i have 2 server direct connect to 1 juniper netscreen sn25 firewall then go to internet, the intel 350 nic is setup at 100mbps (which should be able go up to 1000mbps).

the problem is this limit the data trasfer rate (send & receive ) between this two xen server, if one server use as san and another use to host the vm and use the san as storage repo, the speed will be limited.

i was think to replace the firewall, if i get cisco asa-5505, does this firewall provide 1000mbps switch compare to juniper which only 100mbps?

this question seen silly, but i was confuse. please advice.

Answer (score 1):

No, the Cisco ASA 5505 only provides 100Mbps interface ports. I would suggest purchasing a dedicated Gigabit switch rather than relying on your firewall's interfaces.